# Create dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I create a dictionary with multiple values per key from 2 lists?

For example, I have:

```
>>> list1 = ['fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetable']

>>> list2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']
```

And, I want something to the effect of:

```
>>> dictionary = {'fruit': ['apple', 'banana'], 'vegetable': ['carrot']}
```

I have tried the following so far:

```
>>> keys = list1
>>> values = list2
>>> dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> dictionary
    {'fruit': 'banana', 'vegetable': 'carrot'}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `dict.setdefault` and a simple for-loop:

```
>>> list1 = ["fruit", "fruit", "vegetable"]
>>> list2 = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"]
>>> dct = {}
>>> for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
...     dct.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
... 
>>> dct
{'fruit': ['apple', 'banana'], 'vegetable': ['carrot']}
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

> `setdefault(key[, default])`
>
> If `key` is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert `key` with a value of `default` and return `default`. `default` defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [*collections.defaultdict*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for such tasks :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
...    d[i].append(j)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'vegetable': ['carrot'], 'fruit': ['apple', 'banana']})
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit different from the other answers. It is a bit simpler for beginners.

```
list1 = ['fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetable']
list2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']
dictionary = {}

for i in list1:
    dictionary[i] = []

for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    dictionary[list1[i]].append(list2[i])
```

It will return

```
{'vegetable': ['carrot'], 'fruit': ['apple', 'banana']}
```

This code runs through `list1` and makes each item in it a key for an empty list in `dictionary`. It then goes from 0-2 and appends each item in `list2` to its appropriate category, so that index 0 in each match up, index 1 in each match up, and index 2 in each match up.